# TypeError: Cannot read property 'salida' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, ionic-framework

Me aparece un error, el cual interpreto que sucede por que el método que trato de llamar o invocar no existe. Lo raro o extraño de todo esto, es que utilizo la misma forma de inyectar el servicio, y no ocurre dicho error, bueno sin mas preámbulo, colocare el código y la explicación.

#### historial.js

```
angular.module('historialApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'horarioEstudiante', 'calificacionesEstudiante'])    
       .controller('borrarHistorial', borrarHistorial)
       .factory('salirApp', salirApp);

salirApp.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform', '$ionicHistory', '$timeout', '$cordovaSQLite'];

function salirApp($ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $timeout, $cordovaSQLite) {

    function salida() {

        var BackButton = 0;

        $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {            

            if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'menuestu' || $ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'menuprof') {

                if (BackButton === 0) {

                    BackButton++;
                    window.plugins.toast.showLongCenter("Presione nuevamente para salir");

                    $timeout(function() {
                        BackButton = 0;
                    }, 2500);

                } else {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }

            } else {
                if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'login') {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                } else {
                    $ionicHistory.goBack();
                }
            }

        }, 100);

    }

    return {
        salida: salida
    };

}
```

En este archivo tengo un `factory`, el cual, cuando inyecto el modulo en otro, y llamo el método, cuando lo necesito.

#### horarioestu.js

```
angular.module('horarioEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'btford.socket-io', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('mostrarHorarioEstu', mostrarHorarioEstu);


mostrarHorarioEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerHorarioEstu', 'socket', 'salirApp'];

function mostrarHorarioEstu($scope, obtenerHorarioEstu, socket, salirApp) { 
  
    salirApp.salida();

}
```

En el código expuesto anteriormente, inyecto el modulo `historialApp`, para llamar el *factory* `salirApp`, y luego invoco el método `salida`

#### perfilestu.js

```
angular.module('perfilEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('mostrarPerfilEstu', mostrarPerfilEstu);

mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfilEstu', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile', 'salirApp'];

function mostrarPerfilEstu($scope, obtenerPerfilEstu, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, salirApp, $element) {   

    salirApp.salida();

}
```

En el código expuesto anteriormente en el fichero **perfilestu.js**, donde hago lo mismo que en el archivo **horarioestu.js**, pero cuando voy a ingresar a esta interfaz aparece el error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'salida' of undefined at new mostrarPerfilEstu
```

Comment: Capaz que hablo pavada. Pero si en el archivo historial.js agregás el módulo "perfilEstudiante"?  O sea, en la primera línea, en vez de `angular.module('historialApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'horarioEstudiante', 'calificacionesEstudiante'])` poner `angular.module('historialApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'horarioEstudiante', 'calificacionesEstudiante', 'perfilEstudiante'])`?

Comment: Pues podría ser, pero creo que pude solucionarlo, creo que el error estaba en el orden que colocaba lo que inyectaba en el controller del **perfilestu.js**, pero cualquier cosa te comento si noe s asi